# Android ActionBarSherlock ProgressBar always Indeterminate

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

I've got an activity that extends SherlockActivity but the progressbar is always indeterminate, even without setting it to true or after setting it to false.

I've already checked the import:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window;
```

The activity in fact extends Sherlock:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockActivity {
```

Here is the onCreate method:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

In no place I set it to true, but it still appears without leaving.

The manifest:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Any ideas of what might be causing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

I can't find an explanation for why it is always indeterminate.
Also, this definitely is not working

```
getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
```

However using

```
getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Also, be sure to call getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false) AFTER calling setContentView(...);

Answer (score 2):

I am just enabling and disable the ActionBarShareLock ProgressBar.

Not sure but might be helpful to you.
Below is my code:

```
public class IndeterminateProgress extends SherlockActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //This has to be called before setContentView and you must use the
    //class in com.actionbarsherlock.view and NOT android.view
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.iprogress);

    findViewById(R.id.enable).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.disable).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Updated**

have you try with this:

```
  getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminate(indeterminate);
```

**OR**

```
 getSherlock().setProgressBarVisibility(visible);
```

I mean try with call getSherlock() before going to Ideterminate or change its visibility.

Let me comment of result.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks, @iDroid Explorer; made a similar sample in this activity (with a toast, to be sure) but it never goes away. awkward...

Comment: You mean you are not able to disable the Progressbar ?

Comment: Basically that is true, when I set         setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
the ProgressBar keeps there.

Comment: unfortunately, as I expected, it didn't solve the issue. It is really something wrong because in the start of the activity the progressbar is already indeterminate (even if I don't set it)

Comment: Hummm, well dont know about your condition. but here i can also able to disable with same code.

Comment: just awkward; I'll take a look at it with later and if I find something I'll post it. thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try out as below:

> ```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
>       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
>       setContentView(R.layout.browser);
>       setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
>       setProgressBarVisibility(true);         
>       findViewById(R.id.enable).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View arg0) {
>          setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
>              setProgressBarVisibility(false);
>     }
>   });
>     }
> ```

Comment: thank you; i've tried the exact example (with my layout) but it didn't fix it. Moreover, I've tried it in both HTC and Galaxy I...

Comment: Do you have any view for which you are handling the progress event ?

Comment: @GrIsHu this issue happened only in API version 8

Answer (score 1):

do this
just before you declare your activity view pass the progress bar and after defining your view disable the visibility of the progress bar then on your whatever click enable the visivility of the bar

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
            setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            ......
                ......
                     .........
                      ...OnClick()
                          {
                           setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                            }
                             .............
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the same problem I had and it taken me 5 hours to debug ABS to investigate the problem. The solution is very simple:

Use:

> com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS

Like:

> requestWindowFeature(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

Instead of:

> android.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS